# JQuery to Javascript Document.Write

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle (Uses JQuery) - http://jsbin.com/ponikasa/1/edit

I know JQuery is Javascript, but for the sake of an argument how do you write the following in pure Javascript without the need for a js library like JQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.preview-site').on('click', function(){
    window.open('javascript:document.write("'+ $('.workflow').val() +'")', 'Opened Page', 'width=660, height=440');
    return false;
  });
});
```

I tried this, but doesn't work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var preview = document.getElementsByClassName("preview-site"),
      code = document.getElementsByClassName("workflow")[0].value;

  preview.onClick = function() {
    window.open('javascript:document.write("'+ code = +'")', 'Opened Page', 'width=660, height=440');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: firstly code is an array so it should be code[0].value

Comment: No point in editing/fixing code after each comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well to write in javascript you would do the following

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var previewSite = this.querySelectorAll('.preview-site');

  var handler = function() {
    var workflow = document.querySelector('.workflow')
    window.open('javascript: document.write(' + workflow.value + ')', 'Opened Page', 'width=660, height=440')
    return false;
  };

  for( var i = 0; i < previewSite.length; i++) {
    previewSite[i].addEventListener('click', handler);    
  }
});
```

The problem you had is `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, so you cannot use `value` or `onclick` on the collection.

I use `querySelectorAll` because it's easier and has almost better support that `getElementsByClassName`

I don't usually answer questions like this, but I am **highly** supportive of anyone that uses jQuery that want's to actually learn javascript it's self

also, in your question, you have `onClick`, for the event handler you want `onclick`

For one minor performance improvement you could move `workflow` out of `handler`, that way it won't fetch it on every click, only do this if you don't intend to add dynamic `.workflow`

Yeah, and also. *(as pointed out in comments)* `window.onload` is not the same as `document ready`, `window.onload` will wait for images & media to be fully loaded, so use `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: Sorry been doing a bit of reading. Anyway JSLint said to not make functions inside of loops. I removed the loop to satisfy JSBin - http://jsbin.com/ponikasa/2/edit 

The page is opened, but the value is not being embedded as the html of the new dom. Can you explain why this is?

Answer (score 3):

One of the things jQuery selectors do is try to abstract the "array" when calling functions and assigning handlers.  Consider something like this:

```
$('.preview-site').on('click', function(){
    // code
});
```

This code doesn't just assign the click handler.  On a lower level than that presented by the jQuery interface, this *iterates* the *array* of `.preview-site` elements and assigns the click handlers to each element.  Sometimes it's one element, sometimes it's many.  (Sometimes it's none.)  jQuery makes the interface the same regardless of the count.

Without it, you need to handle that difference explicitly.  These values are arrays:

```
var preview = document.getElementsByClassName("preview-site"),
    code = document.getElementsByClassName("workflow");
```

Even if each one only finds a single element by that class name, the result from `document.getElementsByClassName()` is an array.  So even if the array has only one element, it's still an array.  And you can't assign a handler to an array, you need to assign it to each element in the array.  Potentially something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < preview.length; i++) {
    preview[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.open('javascript:document.write("'+ code[i].value[0] +'")', 'Opened Page', 'width=660, height=440');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Naturally, you'd probably want to put in some checks to ensure that the two arrays are the same length before assuming that for each `preview` element there exists a `code` element.  But the principle is the same.  You just need to account for the enumeration of the array manually.

Comment: use `object.addEventListener` instead of `object.click` for a better 1:1 and a sidenote: same should be done for the `window.ready` : use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't even thought to address the rest of the code.  Just the main point about the array iteration.  I've updated the answer, though I'm sure there are additional improvements that can be made.  Thanks!

Comment: @Connor I too was not looking close enough or giving a proper translation. I just saw that OP went from `$(document).ready` to `window.onload` which isn't really the same thing (but you showed that in your post, so +1)